# How to add WCF Service Reference when using net.msmq

Tags: wcf, msmq, biztalk

How do you start a WCF client when using the service is only available on net.msmq
 - when you use the "Add Service Reference", you get an error ...

*The MetadataExchangeClient instance could not be initialized because no Binding is available for scheme 'net.msmq'. You can supply a Binding in the constructor, or specify a configurationName.
Parameter name: scheme
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.*

For example, I've got the BizTalk example WcfNetAdapterPublishing from MSDN up and running, and it includes a console test client that uses the service at ...

```
net.msmq://localhost/private/WcfNetMsmqAdapterPublishing
```

so it seems it's possible, but I can't see anyway to start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose the same service and data contracts over say `basicHttpBinding` on a separate endpoint, create the service reference using that endpoint (and Metadata Exchange for it), and then manually adapt your app.config to use `netMsmqBinding` instead.

Or you could just share the contracts assembly with your service and data contracts between the server and the client project, and create the config manually (really not a big deal), and create your client proxy in code, using `ChannelFactory<T>`. Since you're already using the `netMsmqBinding`, you're definitely using .NET on both ends of the wire - so that technique should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a base address (in addition to the net.msmq one you have) with a prefix of `http`. So, with net.msmq in  the example you gave, you would add this:

```
http://localhost/private/WcfNetMsmqAdapterPublishing ...
```

You then need to add an endpoint for `mex` like so:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Then start your service (outside of Visual Studio)... and then add reference to the `http://` endpoint you added...

Here's an example of one of mine:

```
<service name="Services.Archiver" behaviorConfiguration="FacebookArchiver">
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="netMsmqBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="msmq" 
                contract="Services.IArchiver" 
                behaviorConfiguration="validator" />
      <endpoint address="mex" 
                binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.msmq://localhost/private/Archiver" />
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost/private/Archiver" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
```

In this example you would simply add service reference to http://localhost/private/Archiver... done.